# html inline style not applying in Jupyter notebook cells anymore

Tags: html, css, jupyter-notebook, markdown, jupyter

When passing `style` argument along with a `<span>` starting block, I changed `font-size` and `font-family` and all of that in my Jupyter notebook's individual cells. Like so-

```
<span style="font-family:Verdana">Irrelavant text.</span>
```

OR

```
# Model Building                        <span style="font-size:12px">[Jump to Beginning](#top)</span>
```

It was working just fine until about a week or so ago, when all of the `style` effects in my notebook just disappeared. The code is obviously still there in the markdown cells but it just doesn't show the intended result. The same notebook still works and loads the style when ran on Kaggle or JupyterLab. Did Jupyter notebooks stop supporting it or did I change something unintentionally? What could be a workaround or maybe even a fix for the issue without changing the code?

It used to look like this (avoid the black theme, screenshot is from JupyterLab)-

[image]

And now it looks like this-

[image]

As you can see, the `font-size:12px` has no effect anymore. Same goes for `font-family` and the likes.

**Edit:** [Notebook](https://github.com/vyaduvanshi/helper-files/blob/master/SO.ipynb)

Comment: Which version are you using of jupyter notebook?

Comment: Yeah I removed that part of my comment, which version are you using?

Comment: 6.4.1 for notebook, and 7.26.0 for ipython if that's useful

Comment: It could be that the font-size is being overwritten from somewhere else?  See if this works `<span style="font-size:12px !important">[Jump to Beginning](#top)</span>`

Comment: @Kudos gives me the exact same output as without `!important` and still not applying the `style` attribute. If it is being overwritten from elsewhere, it happened by itself as I didn't change anything.

Comment: Can you share your notebook or the code? It's not really possible to do anything other than a guess based on the information you have provided. I don't think this has to do with a Jupyter in general.

Comment: @Kat I have already added the code in the question. This is not the problem of a particular notebook but even a new one. I am adding a github link to the notebook just in case it's helpful.

Comment: From Jupyter: "Javascript and CSS in Markdown cells" "...styling the notebook can only be done via either custom.css or CSS in HTML output. The latter only have an effect if the notebook is trusted, because otherwise the output will be sanitized just like Markdown." [Source](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/security.html?highlight=css#javascript-and-css-in-markdown-cells) Since it *was* working, is this a **trust issue**?

Comment: @Kat that is interesting. I just made my notebook trusted and it still doesn't change it, even after relaunching the kernel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is the answer you wanted, but it works. It is scalable, too. I usually use Python with Atom, XCode, or RMarkdown in RStudio, so I am not all that familiar with the ins and outs of Jupyter's interface.

First, I noticed that I could see the text rendered as expected when I went to print preview. However, I thought that that was pretty useless. What are you going to do? Go to print preview every time you write something? What's the purpose of an interactive notebook at that point?

I digress.

Okay, so what I found that worked... in no way is this an idea that is originally mine...

### Custom CSS

Adding a custom CSS file, but not the 'change it all' thing that the Jupyter help files suggest...

**Step 1)**
Create a styles folder in the same directory as the ipynb file.

[image]

**Step 2)**
Within the styles folder, create a CSS file.

[image]

**Step 3)**
Within that CSS file, write the two tag styles and any others you desire.

[image]

Here's that code (pictures of code are annoying).

```
div.verdana {    
    font-family:verdana;
}

div.bigger {
    font-size: 20pt;
}
```

### Within the ipynb File

**Step 4)**
Next, add the `div` tags to your ipynb file in a Markdown cell:

```
<div class='verdana'>This should be Verdana font.</div>
```

The result after running the cell:

[image]

**Step 5)**
Do the same thing with the bigger font.
You highlighted the desire for `font-size:20px`; I inadvertently did `font-size:20pt`. Just change the `pt` to `px`.

Add the `div` tags to your ipynb file in a Markdown cell:

```
<div class="bigger">Font size 20px</div>
```

The result after running the cell:

[image]

**Step 6)**
Somewhere in the notebook, you need to call the link to the CSS file. I just added it to the end:

```
from IPython.core.display import HTML
def css_styling():
    styles = open("./styles/custom.css", "r").read()
    return HTML(styles)
css_styling()
```

It can go at the end because the entire kernel executes initially (so it doesn't need to be *before* you call the tags.

**FYI**
I did try to use `magic`, but it **did not work** for the font-family:

```
%%html
<style>
// add your CSS styling here
div.verdana {    
    font-family:verdana;
}

div.bigger {
    font-size: 20pt;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Although this is not exactly cell independent, it does the job! Also, magic seems to be working for me with the font-family so I don't need a separate file. I'll wait a while for a cell independent answer and if I don't get one, I'll accept your answer. (thanks for the elaborate and candid answer!)

Answer (score 4):

Inline styles in Markdown cells were temporarily removed in a security fix addressing a different sanitization issue earlier last month and restored in just released [v6.4.4](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/releases/tag/v6.4.4). Please update your notebook installation for the old styling in Markdown to work again.

Jupyter**Lab** 3.2.2, 3.2.3 and 3.2.4 are also affected by a similar issue. It was already fixed in [PR #11510](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/pull/11510) and the fix was released in JupyterLab [v3.2.5](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/releases/tag/v3.2.5) on 10th December 2021.

Comment: I seem to be running v6.4.6 in JupyterLab and no longer have access to inline CSS. This _used_ to work:
```html
# Data Prep (for All Data)

<div style="border: dotted 2px red; background-color: rgb(250,230,230);">
    <b>Blah</b> blah, blah.
</div>
```
But no longer does. `jupyter --version` output (slightly trimmed):
```bash
IPython: 7.29.0
ipykernel: 6.5.0
ipywidgets: 7.6.5
jupyter_client: 7.0.6
jupyter_core: 4.9.1
jupyterlab: 3.2.4
nbclient: 0.5.9
nbconvert: 6.3.0
nbformat: 5.1.3
notebook: 6.4.6
traitlets: 5.1.1
```

Comment: Blech, sorry, have tried to go back and edit this so it's formatted properly and can no longer do so. Nor does my attempt to use what I though what the correct approach based on additional reading of the docs work either! The above is basically intended to show a Markdown cell with limited Markedown formatting (a header) and then some simple HTML+CSS style--which has worked fine until I rebuilt my Docker image and updated to the latest version of JupyterLab. But if it's really/just a notebook issue then 6.4.6 _should_ be fine according the answer above.

Comment: Ah, cheers for that. Will keep an eye on the Docker stacks for 3.2.5 or rollback to 3.2.1 if I decide I can’t live without my CSS for a few weeks.

Comment: 3.2.5 is now released: https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/releases/tag/v3.2.5